# ffmpeg with webcam input and stereoscopic output

Tags: ffmpeg, stereo-3d

I'd like to take video fed from my webcam, and output it (live) as stereoscopic video using ffmpeg.  I'm testing in Windows, but eventually I intend to use Linux.  Here's what I've crafted so far...

`ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" stereo3d=al:sbsl Desktop\test.mpg`

At this point, I'm just trying to stream to a file.  Once I know the filters work, I'll figure out how to stream to the display.  Unfortunately, this isn't working.

`ffmpeg version N-88193-g5834cba05e Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
  libavformat    58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  0.100 /  7.  0.100
  libswscale      5.  0.100 /  5.  0.100
  libswresample   3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Integrated Webcam':
  Duration: N/A, start: 341189.309000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
[NULL @ 000001667e3ee5e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'stereo3d=al:sbsl'
stereo3d=al:sbsl: Invalid argument`

Without the `stereo3d` filter, I'm able to stream the video without any issues.  I'm trying to use `stereo3d` to just grab every other frame, and place it side-by-side.  (Eventually, I'd like to figure out how to distort the output to work with Google Cardboard... but one step at a time.)

So, the ask is this: what's wrong with my `stereo3d` filter? According to the documentation, it should work just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -vf stereo3d=al:sbsl Desktop\test.mpg
```

`stereo3d` is a filter and as such is added as an argument to a simple filtergraph specification (`-filter:v` or its old form `-vf`) or a complex one (`-filter_complex`). Depending on your shell, it's also best to enclose the argument in quotes.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick.  I suppose the takeaway is to tell ffmpeg that I'm trying to apply a video filter. :) Thank you!